# How to handle outcome variables during imputation of missing data in model building and assessment process?

Tags: cross-validation, missing-data, bias, data-imputation, dependent-variable

Der community

I have a question about the appropriate handling of the imputation of missing data to get an unbiased estimate of prediction accuracy during model building and assessment. While statistical modelling has a wealth of theoretical and practical information about missing data, there is less available for prediction modelling/machine learning. I want to build a prediction model and I am unsure how to handle the **outcome observations Y** during the model building/validation and testing procedure.

If I impute missing data among the **predictors** in the training data set using (for example) knn, I would develop the imputation model using X and Y in the training data set before I start identifying the best hyper parameters to develop a prediction model. I would use the imputation model to impute missing data in the validation data set to identify the best hyperparameters using cross-validation.

Would I include the outcome **observations (Y)** or would I remove the outcomes and treat them as missing to simulate a real-life situation? The same questions apply to the assessment of the final model in the hold-out test data set (or in the outer loop of nested cross-validation)?

I wonder if I can keep the outcome observations (Y) in the hyperparameter tuning step (validation data set) because my model performance will be only assessed in the hold-out/test data set, and including the outcome in the validation data set may improve the prediction model. However, I would not use the outcome in the final test data set (for internal validation)?

Answer (score 2):

Imputing the target variable in validation and test (especially the test) sets is not a good idea. With the test set, we look for real world performance evaluation; and the better your data resembles real data, the higher your chances of getting a more realistic performance measure before you deploy your model. Slightly less critical, but validation set should also mimic your test data, so better to exclude it for target imputation.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, my question was not precise. My question referred to data that are missing among the predictor. I will edit my question.

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood your question. Can you elaborate on your question in the OP: "Would I include the Y variable or would I remove the outcomes and treat them as missing to simulate a real-life situation?"? Do you mean using imputing missing values in the features of validation set using the features and target of training set?

Comment: Thanks for keeping interested. I clarified my question, esp. about my use of outcome variable, outcome and Y and added more information about the use of the imnputation model:  I want to develop an imputation model using the training data set (followed by developing a prediction model using hyper parameter tuning) and to use this imputation model to predict missing values in the feature variables. My question is when do I include the observed outcomes in the imputation process.