# Removing observations with missing target values in the test set

Tags: predictive-models, multiple-imputation, dependent-variable

I'm building my first predictive model and seem to be having a fundamental confusion about missing target values.

I'm predicting treatment outcome (with both regression and classification methods for different definitions of the outcome). 20% of patients in my dataset have missing target values. I don't want to exclude them for 2 reasons: 1. loss of power and 2. from all I've read, albeit within statistics not ML, unless missing outcome is MCAR (mine isn't), removing them introduces bias. In predictive modeling context, bias in coefficient estimates is not a concern but if I understand correctly, it will negatively affect model performance (the patients who have missing outcome also have "worse" values on all important predictors, so if I remove them, I remove the variance in my dataset, but there will be similar observations in my test set and the model will not be able to predict them well (?))

So, I'm considering different options:

1. Resample >> multiple imputation of train and test set separately to avoid data leakage. Use observed outcome values to impute predictors and **impute outcome as well**.
2. Same but only use outcome for imputation of predictors and then drop all rows with missing outcome
3. Same but don't use observed outcome for predictor imputation (as suggested [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.201400004))
4. Drop rows with missing outcome from the start >> resample >> only impute predictors
5. Same as #1 but drop rows with missing outcome in the test set

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577842/how-to-handle-outcome-variables-during-imputation-of-missing-data-in-model-build?rq=1) the comment appears to suggest #5 saying that

> Imputing the target variable in validation and test (especially the
> test) sets is not a good idea. With the test set, we look for real
> world performance evaluation; and the better your data resembles real
> data, the higher your chances of getting a more realistic performance
> measure before you deploy your model.

And this is the part I find very confusing and need community wisdom. If the test set needs to resemble real data, how is dropping rows with missing outcome helping with that? In real data, I will have this type of patients in both, test set and later out-of-sample evaluation (in the clinic).

**tl;dr What should I do with missing target values in the test set?**